# wordpress custom post type issue - thumbnail in custom post page adds margin to row

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have added a featured image function to have the featured image displayed as a thumbnail in the custom post page (products).

The issue is that the image's div has too much width/padding/margin which creates this kind of view:
[image]

^^^ How horrible, right?

Here are the relevant functions that i've annotated:

```
// GET FEATURED IMAGE
function ST4_get_featured_image($post_ID) {
    $post_thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id($post_ID);
    if ($post_thumbnail_id) {
        $post_thumbnail_img = wp_get_attachment_image_src($post_thumbnail_id, 'featured_preview');
        return $post_thumbnail_img[0];
    }
}
// ADD NEW COLUMN
function ST4_columns_head($defaults) {
    $defaults['featured_image'] = 'Featured Image';
    return $defaults;
}
function ST4_columns_content($column_name, $post_ID) {
    if ($column_name == 'featured_image') {
        $post_featured_image = ST4_get_featured_image($post_ID);
        if ($post_featured_image) {
            // HAS A FEATURED IMAGE
            echo '<img src="' . $post_featured_image . '" />';
        }
        else {
            // NO FEATURED IMAGE, SHOW THE DEFAULT ONE
            echo '<img src="https://placehold.it/60x60?text=insert+pic+here"';
        }
    }
}
add_filter('manage_posts_columns', 'ST4_columns_head');
add_action('manage_posts_custom_column', 'ST4_columns_content', 10, 2);
```

Comment: can you please show what's html here behind this space? a screenshot of inspect element.

Comment: try this `add_action('admin_head', 'thumbnail_admin_head');

function thumbnail_admin_head() {   
    echo '.column-img { width:100px !important; overflow:hidden }';   
    echo '</style>';
}`